# How to make Rails app on OpenShift notice new env variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, openshift

I recently pushed a change to my Openshift Rails app that required some additional environment variables in an initializer. I forgot to set the variables before the push, so ran `rhc env set ...` afterwards.

I then restarted the app in order to pick them up; but this didn't work. I saw the following error in the `ruby.log`:

```
[Thu Dec 11 06:52:24 2014] [warn] PassEnv variable GOOGLE_APP_ID was undefined
```

In the end, I made a trivial change to the repo, re-committed and re-pushed. That caused the app to see the new environment variables.

Is there a way to prompt an Openshift app to restart in such a way that it refreshes its env vars?

Comment: What were the exact steps you did to restart the app?

Comment: I tried both the restart button (the curly arrow) on the web dashboard, and `rhc app restart -a app`. I also tried `rhc cartridge restart -c ruby1.9 -a app`. I couldn't easily find an `rhc` command for any kind of more drastic restart.

Comment: The `rhc app restart <appname>` should have done it as it would have restarted your application in an new shell thus grabbing the latest changes in env variables. I would suggest opening a bug here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online

Comment: Thanks - I'll double-check the bug repros when I have a moment, and do that.

Comment: Had an opportunity to test just now (I forgot to set email credentials), and it definitely reproduces. I will raise a bug later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try 'rhc env list -a {yourAppName}' to make sure the environment variables are there. Make sure you don't have a typo.

The most drastic way to restart is to do

'rhc app force-stop  -a {yourAppName}'

and then

'rhc app start  -a {yourAppName}'

Comment: This does actually cause the variables to be picked up, so that'll do as a workaround!